# Laravel - Login sql error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I try to login on Laravel 5.4 I have the following error after entering my email and password on the login page

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'id' inconnu dans where clause (SQL: select * from `acteur` where `id` = 21 limit 1)
```

It's not the right id name it should be `id_biodic_acteur`and not `id`

`acteur` is my user table

Here is my login page :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Se connecter</title>
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="login">
    <img class="logo-img" src="/img/logo.jpg" alt="">

    <h1 class="title">LPO Extranet</h1>

    <form class="form-login" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-input-login{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="email" class="">E-Mail</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-input-pwd{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="password" class="">Mot de passe</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-pwd" name="password" required>

            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
        </label>

        <button type="submit" class="form-input-submit">
            Valider
        </button>

        <a class="" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
            Mot de passe oublié ?
        </a>

    </form>
</body>
```

And i changed a little my login controller :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    protected $primaryKey = "id_biodiv_acteur";
    protected $table = "acteur";

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/pages/birds';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

}
```

My auth routes :

```
 public function auth()
    {
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

        // Password Reset Routes...
        $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
        $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
        $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
        $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    }
```

And here AuthentificatesUsers :

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
        );
    }


    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }

    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Paste your migration for the user table.

Comment: try to put `protected $primaryKey = "id_biodiv_acteur";` & `protected $table = "acteur";` in your `App/User` Model

Comment: $table and $primaryKey are already in my User Model. And i didn't migrate my tables i made them via phpmyadmin

Comment: Why would you do that? Laravel contains functionality for database migrations. Anyhow, it's looking for an ID column which doesn't exist. Is the login route pointing to the right controller?

Comment: Because i made my table with sql workbench and i import it in phpmyadmin. Oh ! Yes it's not the right name for the id, it's "id_biodiv_acteur" and not "id", where can i change this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the built in authentication functionality there is no need to specify a custom `login()` mehtod, simply do:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

And follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication).

The `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait contains all the methods you need. To handle a login POST request you need to use the inbuilt `postLogin()` mehtod.

Simply change your post route:

```
 $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@postLogin');
```

Have a look at all available methods in the [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.html).

Comment: Thank you but all is generate by this command, i just custom the html

Comment: then try getting rid of the `login()` function in your controller, it will overwrite the default method in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`.

Comment: Also, check where your authentication routes are pointing to: `php artisan route:list` and look for URI: auth/login; it will tell you what method it is trying to use.

Comment: So, to be sure, you advise me to delete login() in LoginController.php ?

Comment: Well, as it currently is, your login() is not doing a thing. Check the POST route to login and make sure it points to the right controller. In my case the route is: `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postLogin`.

Comment: It's look like we don't have same version of Laravel ?

Comment: Have a look at my updated response. You are using the `AuthenticatesUsers` class, in your controller - check what methods are available there. Don't get confused by the fact that I call my controller AuthController instead of LoginController.

Comment: Ok, i did what you said and there is this error : "LoginController::postLogin() does not exist" but with "use AuthenticatesUsers;" it should work

Comment: Have a look at the docs for your specific version ( `php artisan --version` ), to see what methods are available (it may be called something different). Alternatively check the class yourself to see what is available there

Comment: In AuthenticatesUsers there is another function call also login which is the one which should work. so i deleted the login function in login controller to use only this function. ( I update my question with the login function)

Comment: Does it work? Does such function do something similar to [postLogin()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L33)?

Comment: I've just seen the updated version. Are you getting any more errors?

Comment: Yep, the same error at the beginning :/ I just need to find where to change the primary key ('id') which is use to the correct one

Comment: What does `getAuthIdentifierName()` return? It should give you the primary key it is using to authenticate; it seems to be using "id" rather than "id_biodiv_acteur". Have you defined the custom primary key in the user model?

Comment: I found this function in GenericUser.php with "return 'id';" so I change it with the correct id but I still have the same error with the same damn "id"

Comment: My bad, it work (needed to clean my cache). Thank you !